# BeautifulSoup - findAll not within certain tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to find a way to find all items within a BeautifulSoup object that have a certain tag that aren't within a certain other tag. For example:

```
<td class="disabled first"> <div class="dayContainer">
      <p class="day"> 29
      </p> <p class="moreLink">
      </p> 
   </div>
</td>
```

I want to find all iterations of `class="dayContainer"`, which is simple enough, but how do I go about finding all of those that aren't first within `class="diabled"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run a filter for tags whose .parent doesn't have that class attribute. Something like

```
filteredDayContainers = [tag for tag in soup.find_all('div', 
    attrs = {'class': 'dayContainer'}) 
    if "disabled" not in tag.parent['class']]
```

Comment: Thanks! However, it keeps coming back with 'NoneType object is not callable'. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Try to isolate the issue - which object is turning out to be `None`? Is it soup? tag.parent? I'm assuming you're running BeautifulSoup on your HTML string and storing the result as `soup` ...

Comment: Scratch that. Used find_all instead of findAll. Silly me. Issue resolved, you suggestion did the trick!