# Issue with finding parent of a particular tag in html using python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to fetch parent element of a particular tag using below mentioned code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice
page1= urllib2.urlopen('http://www.sfr.fr/mobile/telephones?vue=000029&tgp=toutes-les-offres&typesmartphone=se-android&typesmartphone=se-apple&typesmartphone=se-bada&typesmartphone=se-rim-blackberry&typesmartphone=se-windows&p=0').read()
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1)
price_parent = soup1.findParents('div')
print price_parent
```

**Problem:** Output which I am getting after running this code returns Null array `[]`, if I use `findParent` instead of Parents then also it returns `None` value.

My actual problem is similar to this [BeautifulSoup - findAll not within certain tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777250/beautifulsoup-findall-not-within-certain-tag)

To solve my actual problem I need to get parents of elements for which I am getting `None` value as mentioned above.

Please help me in solving this issue and pardon my ignorance as I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.findParents()` does not do what you think it does. It finds the parents of the *current element* that match the search. You are trying to find the parents of a page element, which is already the top-level element.

If you had a structure like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="foo">
            <span id="bar">Some text</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

where `soup` is a BeautifulSoup variable for the whole structure, you can find the `span` with:

```
spanelement = soup.find('span', id='bar')
```

and then calling `.findParent('div')` will return a result, namely the `<div class="foo">` element.

So, calling `.findParents()` on a top-level element will *always* return an empty result, there *are no parents*. Call it on something that does have a parent element instead.